# Phonegap notification Error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i'm a newbie at phonegap, i'm trying to show a notification with a code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Notification Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }

        function showDisclaimer(){
                navigator.notification.confirm(
                    'Message',      // message
                    disclaimerDismiss,          // callback
                    'Disclaimer',               // title
                    'Si','No'                   // buttonNames
                );
            }
            function disclaimerDismiss(buttonIndex) {
                if(buttonIndex = 1){
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="#" onclick="showDisclaimer(); return false;">Show Disclaimer</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

i got error when i try to hit the button,i got error

> "cannot call method confirm of undefined"

but i got no error on

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

so i think the problem is the notification object. How should i set up my project to make it works? my current plugins installed in the project are

> 'org.apache.cordova.core.AudioHandler',
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.camera', 
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.file',
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.file-transfer'
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation',
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.media-capture'
>   'org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen'

so, what's wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i am an idiot, looking at

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

i found that i missed notifications and vibration plugin, now everything works fine ;)